# Spurious period/linebreak in bibliography with achemso

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[journal=jctcce,a4paper]{achemso}
\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
Foo.\cite{smit54}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib

```
@ARTICLE{smit54,
  AUTHOR = {J. G. Smith and H. K. Weston},
  TITLE = {Nothing Particular in this Year's History},
  YEAR = {1954},
  JOURNAL = {J. Geophys. Res.},
  VOLUME = {2},
  PAGES = {14-15}
}
```

I get a spurious linebreak before the final period in each reference:

[image]

The question is how to avoid it? (On a just-installed TeXLive 2022.)

ETA: This is what I get with `\listfiles`

```
 *File List*
 achemso.cls    2022-09-28 v3.13d Submission to ACS journals
 article.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
 caption.sty    2022/03/01 v3.6b Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2022/03/17 v2.3b caption3 kernel (AR)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
achemso-jctcce.cfg    2022-09-28 v3.13d achemso configuration: J. Chem. Theory 
Comput.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
 natmove.sty    2010/01/15 v1.1a Automatic citation moving with natbib
mciteplus.sty    2013/09/13 v1.2 enhanced mcite
l3backend-pdftex.def    2022-09-28 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
    main.bbl
 ***********
```

And this is the `main.bbl` file:

```
\providecommand{\latin}[1]{#1}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\doi}
  {\begingroup\let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1 \catcode`\}=2 \doi@aux}
\providecommand{\doi@aux}[1]{\endgroup\texttt{#1}}
\makeatother
\providecommand*\mcitethebibliography{\thebibliography}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{endmcitethebibliography}
  {\let\endmcitethebibliography\endthebibliography}{}
\begin{mcitethebibliography}{2}
\providecommand*\natexlab[1]{#1}
\providecommand*\mciteSetBstSublistMode[1]{}
\providecommand*\mciteSetBstMaxWidthForm[2]{}
\providecommand*\mciteBstWouldAddEndPuncttrue
  {\def\EndOfBibitem{\unskip.}}
\providecommand*\mciteBstWouldAddEndPunctfalse
  {\let\EndOfBibitem\relax}
\providecommand*\mciteSetBstMidEndSepPunct[3]{}
\providecommand*\mciteSetBstSublistLabelBeginEnd[3]{}
\providecommand*\EndOfBibitem{}
\mciteSetBstSublistMode{f}
\mciteSetBstMaxWidthForm{subitem}{(\alph{mcitesubitemcount})}
\mciteSetBstSublistLabelBeginEnd
  {\mcitemaxwidthsubitemform\space}
  {\relax}
  {\relax}

\bibitem[Smith and Weston(1954)Smith, and Weston]{smit54}
Smith,~J.~G.; Weston,~H.~K. Nothing Particular in this Year's History. \emph{J.
  Geophys. Res.} \textbf{1954}, \emph{2}, 14--15\relax
\mciteBstWouldAddEndPuncttrue
\mciteSetBstMidEndSepPunct{\mcitedefaultmidpunct}
{\mcitedefaultendpunct}{\mcitedefaultseppunct}\relax
\EndOfBibitem{}

\end{mcitethebibliography}
```

Comment: It seems that somehow a `\par` slips in, because with `\showoutput` we can see that `\parfillskip` is inserted before the final period. The same output is obtained with the several releases of TeX Live I tried.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian (i.e., the distribution package of Ubuntu) with achemso 2021-01-20 v3.13c, there the final period is on the same line as the page numbers.

Comment: @Marijn I installed TeXLive externally (not using the package system), and have achemso 2022-09-28 (see edited question)

Comment: Can you edit in the relevant part of your `.bbl` file? I have `\bibitem[Smith and Weston(1954)Smith, and Weston]{smit54}
Smith,~J.~G.; Weston,~H.~K. Nothing Particular in this Year's History. \emph{J.
  Geophys. Res.} \textbf{1954}, \emph{2}, 14--15\relax` which has no forced break.

Comment: @JosephWright I have exactly the same. I've added the whole `.bbl` to the question.

Comment: I'll look at this a bit later today: probably relates to a change I had to make to support `bibentry`.

Comment: @JosephWright Did you have time to loot at it?

Comment: @Jellby I've reverted the change that caused the issue. I need to think about a better fix longer-term.